# Refresh object in class that is serving child component after getting API response

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following three files (for simplicity, unrelated are excluded):

- `ParentComponent` which encompasses the whole app
- `ChildComponent` which consumes data stored in util class
- `ApiService` which makes API calls and keeps common data and their accessors

After the component mounts, I make 2 API calls and set:

- moduleData in `ParentComponent`
- moduleContent in `ApiService`

The reason I am setting *moduleContent* in *ApiService* is to have a central location for other components at different levels.

The page loads but child component shows no value received which I know there is value there right after it renders.

Not: changing `refreshMe` didn't work.

My question: How can I refresh `moduleContent` in `ApiService.ts`?

Thank you

...

ParentComponent.tsx:

```
export const ParentComponent: React.FC = () => {
    ...
    const [moduleData, setModuleData] = React.useState<ModuleData>()
    const [refreshMe, setRefreshMe] = React.useState<number>(0)
    const {uuid}: any = useParams()
    ...
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!moduleData) {
            ApiService.fetchModuleData({uuid: uuid})
                .then((response: ModuleData) => setModuleData(response))
        }
        ApiService.fetchContent(moduleData.request)
            .then(response => ApiService.moduleContent = response.data.moduleContent)

        setRefreshMe(refreshMe + 1)
    
    }, [uuid, moduleData])

    ....
}
```

ApiService.ts:

```
class ApiService {
    ...
    moduleContent: { [key: string]: string } = {}
    ...
    
    getContentText(key: string): string {
        return Object.keys(this.moduleContent).length === 0
            ? 'Module content is empty'
            : this.moduleContent[key] ?? 'Key not found in module content'
    }
}
export default new ApiService()
```

ChildComponent.tsx:

```
import ApiService from "../../service/ApiService";
...
export const ChildComponent: React.FC<{moduleData: ModuleData, refreshMe: number}> 
= (moduleData, refreshMe) => {
    ...
    useEffect(() => {
        ...
    }, [refreshMe])
    ...

    return (
        ...
        <div key={refreshMe}>
            {
                ApiService.getContentText('key1') // my problem is here! 
                //  It says: content is empty
                //  (I know it is filled right after this component renders)
            }
        </div>
        ...
    )
}
```

Comment: in ChildComponent, what is ApiService? does it refer to ApiService class itself? or is it an instance of it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's beacuse this callback:

```
response => ApiService.moduleContent = response.data.moduleContent
```

is going to event loop, and is invoked after this line is executed and the component has rerendered:

```
        setRefreshMe(refreshMe + 1).
```

I suggest you try chaining `setRefreshMe` after the callback.

```
ApiService.fetchContent(moduleData.request)
        .then(response => ApiService.moduleContent = response.data.moduleContent)
        .then(()=>setRefreshMe(refreshMe + 1))
```

Comment: `.then(()=>setRefreshMe(refreshMe + 1))` didn't work